# Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 330698896 bytes)

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am trying to change the memory_limit in php.ini, the php.ini is saving fine with new memory size, but i keep getting the same memory size issue?? I am using Laravel 5.5 with Homestead.

Would appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks!

Here is the code m trying to run (importing data from one db to another, rest of the tables are fine except for one)

```
    $repair = DB::connection('db')->table('tablename')->get();

    DB::beginTransaction();

    foreach ($repair as $repairs) {

        Model::create([
            'column' => $repairs->column,
             ...so on

        ]);

    };

    DB::commit();
```

Comment: What is causing this problem, changing your memory limit may not solve it and could cause other problems.

Comment: There is something wrong in your code either its recursive so post it down here

Comment: Obviously, there is some memory leak in your code.

Comment: I have the added the code above :)

Comment: Consider to change your program (only when your table you are loading is big). You are allocating 300 megabytes RAM. Depending on your webservers physical ram you will use the entire machine RAM when you have multi user/parallel requests to that shown function.

Comment: The **real** problem is that you're selecting **everything** from one table and then trying to stick EVERYTHING back to database in a single commit. You should be processing a few records at a time.

Comment: thanks guys, will give it a try using CHUNK

Comment: Tried using chunk and data is importing :D

Comment: I disagree with the close reasons here. This code **has** a working, verifyable example of why the code doesn't work. Even though to laravel  users the problem might be obvious, this is an on topic question. It is an X Y problem though. Op has solution Y in mind but it can actually be solved by implenting X. Probaly is a duplicate, but not off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're loading an entire table in memory. don't do that.

Use chunk and place the create method in it's own function. The reason for the own function is that it gives php space to start internal cleanup of used variables etc... because the scope ends.
Also call `gc_collect_cycles()` at the end of your transaction to force a cleanup of unused variables.
This should keep you way within acceptable limits of ram. If you still hit it, try with 250 or 100 each time.

```
    $query = DB::connection('db')->table('tablename')->orderBy('id','asc');
    $query->chunk(500, function($results) {

        DB::beginTransaction();
        $repairMethod = function($repair) {
            Model::create([
                'column' => $repair->column,
                 ...so on
            ]);
        };

       foreach ($results as $repair) {
           $repairMethod($repair)      
       };

       DB::commit();
       gc_collect_cycles();
});
```

Comment: Hi, tried your way, it threw an error saying NEED TO USE ORDERBY with this function, so i used the chunk and orderby now the data is importing fine. thanks

Comment: Glad I could help you out :-)

Comment: The changes i did, I have posted that as an answer :) do have a look. thanks :D

Comment: I see that you unaccepted my answer. Could you accept your own answer instead? If you found my answer helpful you could consider upvoting my answer.

Comment: Your post was already downvoted by someone else, but I upvoted so negative mark is gone :). Thanks

And I am not able to accept my own answer :/

Comment: You'll have to wait wait a before you can accept your own answer. Be sure to return here in a few days to accept your own answer.

Comment: @Tschallacka gave the real idea. He can edit his answer and this answer should be accepted. He deserve it.

Comment: relax @smartrahat lol.
Tschallacka I have accepted your ans, try editing your ans so it wont mislead someone else :)

Comment: Edited it to add a query builder instance.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it, here is the code:

```
    $query = DB::connection('db')->table('tablename')->orderBy('id', 
    'asc');

    $query->chunk(50, function ($ServiceOrders) {

        DB::transaction(function() use ($ServiceOrders) {

            foreach ($ServiceOrders as $repairs) {
                Model::create([
                    'column' => $repairs->column,
                     ...so on
                ]);
            }
        });
    });
```